# Changing underlying planet for ArcGIS Online to be Mars

Tags: arcgis-online, mars

Background: I am a high school teacher with a brand-new ConnectED K-12 account from ESRI for ArcGIS Online and am trying to figure out the very basics to use this for planetary science.

I have loaded maps of Mars, but my measurements are as if the lat/longs were on Earth.

What I've done so far:

Loaded the maps

- basemap: ArcGIS Server - Mars MDIM2.1 Basemap
- layers: ArcGIS Server - Mars Global GIS Overlay Service

both of these servers are from thare_USGS

When I turn on the measurement tool, the widths of common features (e.g. Olympus Mons) are about twice what you'd expect (checked vs JMARS), as if the lat/longs were on Earth rather than Mars.

How do I change (the size of) the underlying planet for measurements?

Comment: Update: So, after talking with ESRI, this is definitely not possible on the K-12 free online account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The measurements are driven by the geometry service. The geometry service on a ArcGIS Online organization currently cannot be configured to a custom geometry service. If you are using Portal for ArcGIS you could switch out the default geometry service to a custom one. This geometry service is used throughout the entire Portal and is not map/app/scene specific.

Comment: I don't think pointing it to another geometry service would help. The problem is that the Measurement widget isn't using GeometryService for certain WKID that it should. This is a bug with the Measurement widget.

Answer (score 0):

There is potential for Esri to fix by early 2017. Currently using online viewers/tools, you would need to push the code on your own server and change the default behavior for the body and/or measure tools. This includes Esri viewers, Cesium, webworldwind, etc.
Now using these Esri layers or WMS layers in GIS applications like ArcMap and QGIS will work if you define the "data frame" as using Mars or a map projection (using Mars or other body).
The trick here is that the online layer is simply degrees (which is well understood) and forcing it though a map projection via the application will correctly transform these layers. Measurements, scale bars, map scales should all be correct.

Comment: Can you please include a reference link to your comment *There is potential for Esri to fix by early 2017*?

Comment: no "references" yet just initial conversations between us (USGS) and NASA. Hold tight and cross your fingers.